# I want to set the mailmessage.from property to simple text

Tags: asp.net, sendmail, smtpclient

I want to set the mailmessage.from property to simple text instead email address. How this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller");
```

Assuming that you want the From to ***display*** "Ben Miller".

Behind the scenes, the "ben@contoso.com" will still exist in the "From".  A valid email address is required, and you can't do anything to change that.